# How to calculate data size in Azure Data Lake within a timeframe. Need to access files in that range based on modified time in ADLS

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have got data nestled in folders and subfolders within Azure Data Lake. Each piece of data comes with a file name, and in ADLS, we can view the modified time. Now, I'm looking to calculate the total storage size of the data stored within a particular timeframe. How can I access files within that specific time range and calculate the total data size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code should work after providing the start time and end time for the range you want to get the size -

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Set up Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("FileCount").getOrCreate()

# ADLS Gen2 storage account details
account_name = "<account-name"
container_name = "<container_name>"
relative_path = "ADL_STG_NEW/attrep_change*"

# Define the start and end timestamps
start_timestamp = datetime.strptime("2023-11-16 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end_timestamp = datetime.strptime("2023-11-17 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# Convert timestamps to milliseconds for comparison
start_timestamp_ms = int(start_timestamp.timestamp()) * 1000
end_timestamp_ms = int(end_timestamp.timestamp()) * 1000

print(start_timestamp_ms)
print(end_timestamp_ms)

# ADLS Gen2 path
adls_base_path = f"abfss://{container_name}@{account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/{relative_path}"


def get_dir_content(ls_path):
    for dir_path in dbutils.fs.ls(ls_path):
        if dir_path.isDir() and ls_path != dir_path.path:
            yield dir_path.path
    
list(get_dir_content(adls_base_path))


for adls_path in list(get_dir_content(adls_base_path)):
    file_list = dbutils.fs.ls(adls_path)
    filtered_files = [
        (file.name, file.modificationTime, file.size) for file in file_list
        if start_timestamp_ms <= file.modificationTime <= end_timestamp_ms
    ]
    file_count = len(filtered_files)
    total_size = sum(file_info[2] for file_info in filtered_files)
    total_size = total_size/(1024*1024)
    print(f"{adls_path},{total_size},{file_count}")
    
start_timestamp_ms = int(start_timestamp.timestamp()) * 1000
end_timestamp_ms = int(end_timestamp.timestamp()) * 1000

file_list = dbutils.fs.ls(adls_path)

filtered_files = [
    (file.name, file.modificationTime, file.size) for file in file_list
    if start_timestamp_ms <= file.modificationTime <= end_timestamp_ms
]
file_count = len(filtered_files)
print(f"Number of files created between {start_timestamp} and {end_timestamp}: {file_count}")


total_size = sum(file_info[2] for file_info in filtered_files)
total_size = total_size/(1024*1024)

print(f"{relative_path},{total_size},{file_count}")

print(f"Total size of files: {total_size} MegaBytes")
```